# How do I add error logging to my Akka streams in an idiomatic fashion?

Tags: scala, logging, akka, akka-stream

I'm currently running an Akka streams setup similar to the following:

```
                 ┌───────────────┐                 
┌─────────────┐  │┌─────────────┐│                 
│REST endpoint│──▶│Queue source ││                 
└─────────────┘  │└──────╷──────┘│                 
                 │┌──────▼──────┐│                 
                 ││   Flow[T]   ││                 
                 │└──────╷──────┘│                 
                 │┌──────▼──────┐│  ┌─────────────┐
                 ││  KafkaSink  │├─▶│ Kafka topic │
                 │└─────────────┘│  └─────────────┘
                 └───────────────┘
```

While this working is well, I'd like to have some insight into the production system, i.e. have there been errors and what kind of errors. For example, I've wrapped the `KafkaSink` into a `RestartSink.withBackoff` and applied the following attributes to the wrapped sink:

```scala
private val decider: Supervision.Decider = {
  case x =>
    log.error("KafkaSink encountered an error and will stop", x)
    Supervision.Stop
}

Flow[...]
  .log("KafkaSink")
  .to(Producer.plainSink(...))
  .withAttributes(ActorAttributes.supervisionStrategy(decider))
  .addAttributes(
    ActorAttributes.logLevels(
      onElement = Logging.DebugLevel,
      onFinish = Logging.WarningLevel,
      onFailure = Logging.ErrorLevel
    )
  )
```

This does provide me with some insight, e.g. I'll get a log message that the downstream has closed as well as the exception that ocurred via the `supervisionStrategy` that I've added.

This solution, however, feels a little bit like a workaround (e.g. logging the exception the supervision strategy), and it also doesn't provide any insight into the behaviour of the `RestartWithBackoffSink`. I could, of course, enable `DEBUG` level logging for that class, but again, that feels like a workaround to be doing in production.

Long story short:

- Are there any obvious shortcomings of the way I'm trying to gain insight into errors happening in my Akka streams
- Is there a better / more idiomatic way of adding logging to Akka streams in production

Answer (score 4):

I think you are almost there!!

Actually, it is the way as described in the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-error.html#logging-errors). Using `log()` [approach](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-cookbook.html#logging-in-streams) gives you more fine-grained control of logging levels for elements flowing through the stream, finish and failure of the stream.Although, I do not prefer to add the log message inside the supervisor strategy. If you do want to show that particular exception, then, create a custom exception, catch it in the supervisor strategy and let Akka log that message for you. You can enable `debug-logging` in Akka stream [config](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/stream/stream-configuration.html) which is by default `off` for additional troubleshooting logging at the DEBUG log level. Apart from that, you can also enable logging at the actor level.(see this [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/configuration-reference.html)).

I think in production, there might be two ways to log the errors:

1)  log or rethrow exception in the recover stage. This way all exceptions from upstream will be caught and logged:

```
object AkkaStreamRecap extends App {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("AkkaStreamsRecap")
  implicit val materialiser = ActorMaterializer()
  import system.dispatcher

  val source = Source(-5 to 5) 
  val sink = Sink.foreach[Int](println)
  val flow = Flow[Int].map(x => 1 / x)

  val runnableGraph = source.
    via(flow).
    recover {
      case e => throw e
    }.
    to(sink)

  runnableGraph.run()
}
```

Output:

```
0
0
0
0
-1
[ERROR] [03/06/2020 16:27:58.703] [AkkaStreamsRecap-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://AkkaStreamsRecap/system/StreamSupervisor-0/flow-0-0-ignoreSink] Error in stage [Recover(<function1>)]: / by zero
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at com.personal.akka.http.chapter1.AkkaStreamRecap$.$anonfun$flow$1(AkkaStreamRecap.scala:41)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction1$mcII$sp.apply(JFunction1$mcII$sp.java:23)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.Map$$anon$1.onPush(Ops.scala:54)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processPush(GraphInterpreter.scala:523)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processEvent(GraphInterpreter.scala:480)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:376)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:606)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.init(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:576)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.tryInit(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:682)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.preStart(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:731)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundPreStart(Actor.scala:550)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundPreStart$(Actor.scala:550)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.aroundPreStart(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:671)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:676)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:547)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:569)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:293)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:228)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:241)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

2) define custom supervision strategy and use it in stream attributes or in materializer settings:

```
object AkkaStreamRecap extends App {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("AkkaStreamsRecap")

  private val decider: Supervision.Decider = {
    case e: ArithmeticException =>
      println("Arithmetic exception: Divide by Zero")
      Supervision.Stop
  }

  implicit val materialiser = ActorMaterializer(ActorMaterializerSettings(system).withSupervisionStrategy(decider))

  import system.dispatcher


  val source = Source(-5 to 5)
  val sink = Sink.foreach[Int](println)
  val flow = Flow[Int].map(x => 1 / x)

  val runnableGraph = source.via(flow).log("divide by zero").to(sink)

  runnableGraph.run()
}
```

output:

```
0
0
0
0
-1
Arithmetic exception: Divide by Zero
[ERROR] [03/06/2020 16:37:00.740] [AkkaStreamsRecap-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka.stream.Log(akka://AkkaStreamsRecap/system/StreamSupervisor-0)] [divide by zero] Upstream failed.
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at com.personal.akka.http.chapter1.AkkaStreamRecap$.$anonfun$flow$1(AkkaStreamRecap.scala:26)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction1$mcII$sp.apply(JFunction1$mcII$sp.java:23)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.Map$$anon$1.onPush(Ops.scala:54)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processPush(GraphInterpreter.scala:523)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processEvent(GraphInterpreter.scala:480)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:376)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:606)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.init(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:576)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.tryInit(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:682)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.preStart(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:731)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundPreStart(Actor.scala:550)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundPreStart$(Actor.scala:550)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.aroundPreStart(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:671)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:676)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:547)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:569)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:293)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:228)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:241)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Let me know if it helps!!

P.S... I could not find any source or way in the official documentation on other ways to log the errors.

Comment: RE: "If you do want to show that particular exception" – I don't want to show any particular exception, I want to know when something goes wrong inside the flow. `log(...)`, as far as I'm aware, does not tell me why things failed, only *that* they failed, which is not enough insight for me.

Comment: In this link:https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-error.html#logging-errors, the `log{}`  method is used for logging errors and it shows why things failed.

Comment: I have added sample code to log errors in the flow if any. Let me know if it helps!!